# Can I get a descriptor SURF of each point of image

Tags: image, matlab, surf, descriptor

as indicated in the title, I'm looking to get a Descriptor-SURF for each image point I do not want the interests of points, but the SURF descriptor on each point of the image. The SURF descriptor use an integral image to compute the descriptors

```
% Create Integral Image
iimg=IntegralImage_IntegralImage(img);
```

then an extraction of the interest points

```
FastHessianData.thresh = Options.tresh;
FastHessianData.octaves = Options.octaves;
FastHessianData.init_sample = Options.init_sample;
FastHessianData.img = iimg;
ipts = FastHessian_getIpoints(FastHessianData,Options.verbose)
% Describe the interest points
if(~isempty(ipts))
    ipts = SurfDescriptor_DecribeInterestPoints(ipts,Options.upright, Options.extended, iimg, Options.verbose);
end
```

the function with which the points are got

```
function ipts=FastHessian_getIpoints(FastHessianData,verbose)
% filter index map

filter_map = [0,1,2,3;
    1,3,4,5;
    3,5,6,7;
    5,7,8,9;
    7,9,10,11]+1;

np=0; ipts=struct;

% Build the response map
responseMap=FastHessian_buildResponseMap(FastHessianData);

% Find the maxima acrros scale and space
for o = 1:FastHessianData.octaves
    for i = 1:2
        b = responseMap{filter_map(o,i)};
        m = responseMap{filter_map(o,i+1)};
        t = responseMap{filter_map(o,i+2)};

        % loop over middle response layer at density of the most
        % sparse layer (always top), to find maxima across scale and space
        [c,r]=ndgrid(0:t.width-1,0:t.height-1);
        r=r(:); c=c(:);

        p=find(FastHessian_isExtremum(r, c, t, m, b,FastHessianData));
        for j=1:length(p);
            ind=p(j);
            [ipts,np]=FastHessian_interpolateExtremum(r(ind), c(ind), t, m, b, ipts,np);
        end
    end
end

% Show laplacian and response maps with found interest-points
if(verbose)
    % Show the response map
    if(verbose)
        fig_h=ceil(length(responseMap)/3);
        h=figure;  set(h,'name','Laplacian');
        for i=1:length(responseMap), 
            pic=reshape(responseMap{i}.laplacian,[responseMap{i}.width responseMap{i}.height]);
            subplot(3,fig_h,i); imshow(pic,[]); hold on;
        end
        h=figure; set(h,'name','Responses');
        h_res=zeros(1,length(responseMap));
        for i=1:length(responseMap), 
            pic=reshape(responseMap{i}.responses,[responseMap{i}.width responseMap{i}.height]);
            h_res(i)=subplot(3,fig_h,i); imshow(pic,[]); hold on;
        end
    end

    % Show the maximum points
    disp(['Number of interest points found ' num2str(np)]);
    scales=zeros(1,length(responseMap));
    scaley=zeros(1,length(responseMap));
    scalex=zeros(1,length(responseMap));
    for i=1:length(responseMap)
        scales(i)=responseMap{i}.filter*(2/15);
        scalex(i)=responseMap{i}.width/size(FastHessianData.img,2);
        scaley(i)=responseMap{i}.height/size(FastHessianData.img,1);
    end
    for i=1:np
        [t,ind]=min((scales-ipts(i).scale).^2);
        plot(h_res(ind),ipts(i).y*scaley(ind)+1,ipts(i).x*scalex(ind)+1,'o','color',rand(1,3));
    end
end
```

how to keep all the points without doning this step of detection, then describe all of this points by the SURF descriptor.

Comment: an you describe better what is all that code and how is it relevant to the question?

Comment: SURF consist on a keypoint detector (which retrieves the "interesting" keypoints) and a descriptor. If you want to apply the descriptor to all points, just input a vector with all points to the descriptor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you have clearly the detector and descriptor functions separated:

- `FastHessian_getIpoints` returns the list of interesting keypoints
- `SurfDescriptor_DecribeInterestPoints` computes the SURF descriptor for the given points.

Just get rid of your detector and call the descriptor function providing as an input ALL points in the image.

So variable `ipts` will contain ALL points instead of only those returned by the keypoint detector

Comment: thank you for this valuable information, indeed is exactly what i want to do, but i have a little problem with this how can I affect all point to descriptor , still now I failed to do so, I try `ipts = FastHessianData.img; ` instead of  `ipts = FastHessian_getIpoints(FastHessianData,Options.verbose)` but that give an error : `Error in SurfDescriptor_DecribeInterestPoints (line 17)
if (isempty(fields(ipts))), return; end.` tkanks again for your help

Comment: `FastHessian_getIpoints` will probably return the points in some format that is not consistent with your direct assignation. Therefore some fields will be empty. I would suggest running the detector, checking in which format/structure is returning the points and then creating our own points (all of the points in the image) following this format.

Comment: exactly this is the case, the interest points is a struct, when we find x and y of the point ,the scale of the point and Laplacien. I put 1 for scale and laplacien since it is neutral element. but to recover x and y (spatial pixel position) I have not managed to have them.

Comment: do you have any idea of how can i get it ??

Comment: Not sure, but what I can see is that in the KeyPoint detector function you compute a `responseMap` which probably maps the output with the spatial coordinates. You will have to reverse engineer the code. But since the KeyPoint Descriptor is called with the image and the points it must be a way of recovering the spatial info.

Comment: Thank u for your help, I am grateful